# Rollbar + React: Multiple minified JS and Sourcemaps

Tags: reactjs, rollbar

I'm trying to integrate Rollbar into my ReactJS project. I was able to follow the setup instructions at https://docs.rollbar.com/docs/react and now want to upload my source maps. I have been referring to https://docs.rollbar.com/docs/source-maps/ , where it seems there is only one `minified_url` and `source_map` that can be applied, but my `build/static/js` folder has multiple of those. Which ones should I provide or is there a way to circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API endpoint accepts one source map (and therefore minified URL) at a time, so you need to run curl for each source map.

Comment: and they will be associated together, by version?

Comment: and not overwritten?